# Unable to load modules in ruby

Tags: ruby

I googled it, but no luck
I have a file called mdl.rb and `main.rb`, they both in the same folder
`mdl.rb` has module `Test_module` and method in it called `say_hello`, I want to use that method in my `main.rb`.
So my `main.rb` looks like this:

```
require 'mdl'
say_hello
```

but I get error:

```
in `require': cannot load such file -- mdl (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use

```
require_relative 'mdl.rb'
```

See [Ruby docs for `require_relative`.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative)

(`require_relative 'mdl'` and `require './mdl'` also work, as pointed out in the comments by [@MichaelBerkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski) and [@FélixSaparelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231788/f%c3%a9lix-saparelli) respectively.)

Comment: or `require_relative 'mdl'` without `.rb`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Right, works either way (although I prefer being more explicit).

Comment: I did as you said require_relative 'mdl' and now I get this message: `in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `say_hello' for main:Object (NameError)`